# Detect Changes In Database And Send Changed Row Information To .NET Core 3.1 For Push Notification

Tags: asp.net-core, push-notification, signalr, sqldependency

I have a database containing employee attendance information. The changes in DB is triggered by fingerprint machine not my software, That's Why I can't track SaveChanges() function. Does SQL Dependency works in my case if yes then how to implement it in .NET Core 3.1. If Database Changes is happening outside of my software scope how to detect that change and send that specific changed row id to .NET Core Application for displaying notification.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use `SqlTableDependency`?

I found [this](http://elvanydev.com/SignalR-Core-SqlDependency-part2/) article which seems to be implementing what you desire. It is quite an old article, but maybe you could use the same concept?